# Window sizes and positions after 19.04 upgrade

Tags: 19.04

Window sizes and positions are no longer remembered after upgrading to 19.04. Previous solutions I found for earlier versions don't seem to work either. Is there something I can do now to either have applications launch full screen or remember the size and position? I prefer to not have to write scripts to launch applications and then resize or move windows for each.

Comment: @Nmath I'm talking about launching an application like Firefox within a session. I will make it maximized, then close it, and when I reopen it, it is back to being small and not maximized.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it was a problem with Firefox and a setting to resist fingerprinting, a privacy setting. You can set width and height and still resist fingerprinting by reading this, https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/aopz79/resist_fingerprinting_window_size/